# Apply the custom module optionally

Tags: magento2, module

Is it possible in Magento 2 to apply the custom module only if some condition is `true`?

The module is installed through composer and enabled. The installed module overrides the standard Magento functionality, so if the condition is `false` the default Magento view should be shown.

The condition result depends on the calculation and cannot be stored in the configuration.

The simplified example looks as the following:

- with the URI `/product?module=on` the custom module is applied, it overrides the default module and it is shown on the page
- with the URI `/product?module=off` the default Magento module is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to apply a custom module in Magento 2 only if a certain condition is met. One way to achieve this is by using a plugin or interceptor to modify the behavior of the module.

```
   // Check if the condition is true
   if ($_GET['module'] != 'on') {
       // If the condition is false, return null to allow the default behavior to proceed
       return null;
       // If the condition is true, modify the behavior of the method as needed
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May you specify the class/place where I can make this check?

Comment: You have to define which method your custom module overrides. for example, if custom module override execute() method in controller, you need to create class that run function beforeExecute, then define plugin in `di.xml` file. When the execute() method is called, the plugin intercepts the call and checks the condition. If the condition is false, the plugin will return null, allowing the default behavior to continue. If the condition is true, the plugin will modify the modal's behavior as needed.

Comment: Yes, I got your idea. The problem is that the module I would like control is quite big. It has a lot of view blocks and controller actions. Creating the plugins for each method will nearly override the whole module :) Is it maybe a way to activate/deactivate the whole module completely?

Comment: I am not sure because maybe there is another way to use but i don't know for example but i think it is 1 way you can try or refer from other answers or other source

Comment: Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @Zephyr we should not use a superglobal variable like $_GET, use wrappers instead of superglobal variables. In Magento 2, use the `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request` wrapper class to safely access these values. https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/best-practices/extensions/security/

Comment: @TuVan, thanks for the reminder, my above answer was just an example. I will pay attention to my following answers. Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr No worries. Cheers!